# Page not found (404) The current path, api/posts/1, didn’t match any of these

Tags: django, backend

I'm trying to create an api through Django rest framework and using NextJS for the frontend.

I can get all the post data without any error.

but when i try to get data for one post it gives me and error saying "Page not found (404) The current path, api/posts/1, didn’t match any of these."

Here all of the files in my api folder

api/serilizer.py:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e132y.png

api/urls.py:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07jTJ.png

api/views.py and project/urls.py
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0g8t.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/twh9S.png

Please tell me what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Answer (score 0):

The post url is **api/post/1**

But you are calling **api/posts/1**

Comment: Oh didn't realise that can't believe i spent 3 hours debugging because of a typo

Comment: It happens to all developers at least once. :)